# Javascript + timer

Tags: javascript

See the code below...it changes the image after the page load + 8 sec and then keep on changing every 1 second.

```
setInterval(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
         $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/wtrhwt.jpg');

         setTimeout(function(){
             $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/t8yejty.jpg');

             setTimeout(function(){
                 $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/t2tgw8.jpg');

                 setTimeout(function(){
                     $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/45234.jpg');

                     setTimeout(function(){
                         $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/14134.jpg');

                         setTimeout(function(){
                             $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/124t234grq.jpg');

                             setTimeout(function(){
                                 $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/frbvqw34.jpg');

                                 setTimeout(function(){
                                     $('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/14tqwrbfws.jpg');
                                }, 1000);
                            }, 1000);
                        }, 1000);
                    }, 1000);
                }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}, 8000);
```

This loop execute after 8 sec. I want it to start it from the very first second when the page load. How to do it.

Comment: The. Code. Is. Ugly. You should refactor to use an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

setInterval waits for the 8000 to pass before the function is first called, also you might wanna refactor the code like so:

```
$(function(){
    var images = ['lastwavewinnerimages/wtrhwt.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/t8yejty.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/t2tgw8.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/45234.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/14134.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/124t234grq.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/frbvqw34.jpg',
                'lastwavewinnerimages/14tqwrbfws.jpg'];
    var i = 0;

    function k() {
        $('#person1').attr('src', images[i % images.length]);
        i++;
    }

    setInterval( k, 1000 );
    k();
});
```

Comment: Also I would suggest that you create IMG tag for all these images so that all the images load at the same time. And instead of replacing SRC replace the whole image image.

Comment: Why are you making the function return itself?

Comment: @Asad I guess I'm being overly clever, I'll edit it to be more friendly

Comment: @Esailija It just seems somewhat redundant, if you remove the return and the invocation brackets you get identical results.

Comment: @Asad nope, the difference is that the function is called right away for the first time, rather than waiting for 1000 first to pass. That's why the friendly solution has `k()` after `setInterval`, to call it immediately

Comment: @Douglas it is not global, there is a comma after the array. `var a,b,c;` makes 3 local variables where as `var a; b; c;` makes one local and two global

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, I missed that. I probably missed it because of the lack of indentation, I assumed it was at the same level as the rest of the code in the method.

Comment: Does this really wait for 8000 seconds?

Comment: @Asad this one doesn't. OP's code does, and instead of being a chain of events it is a fishbone.

Comment: @Asad no it doesn't, the op said he wants it to run right away instead of waiting for 8000 milliseconds

Comment: Hey is it OK with you if I copy paste some of this code for a different approach (the massive array etc.)?

Comment: @Asad AFAIRC, all answers here are implicitly licenced under the Creative Commons licence.

Comment: Sure, all answers posted here are [CC-BY-SA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54767/174972)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to set a timeout after every iteration:

```
(function() {
    var imagearray = ['lastwavewinnerimages/wtrhwt.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/t8yejty.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/t2tgw8.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/45234.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/14134.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/124t234grq.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/frbvqw34.jpg',
                                'lastwavewinnerimages/14tqwrbfws.jpg'];
    var i = 0; //credit goes to Esailija

    (function nextimg() {
        $('#person1').attr('src', imagearray[i++ % imagearray.length]);
        setTimeout(nextimg, 1000);
    })();
})();
```

Comment: Note: the only difference between this and the other answer is the use of `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` to do the same loop.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah pretty much. Also, the way I am setting the timeout is slightly different, because I can just invoke the function without having to return anything, since I am not passing the function to another function. This makes the code cleaner IMO.

Comment: @JanDvorak Another critical advantage of this approach is that you can set the timeout within the load handler of the image, which makes sure the next one is shown 1s after the image is actually loaded. This can't be done with setinterval.

Comment: Good point - but then you should also attach an `error` handler on the image in case it doesn't load ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Its a duplicate of [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

All you need to do is put your code under window.onload event. Your code will run just after the page load. You may not get expected result when you change the image. Because it will start loading the image when you change the image source. If you preload your images you will get the expected result. Here are the 3 ways to preload images.

[3 Ways to Preload images](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Comment: This question being a duplicate should be a comment.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using setInterval, write a recursive function like this.

```
function loopImages() {
   setTimeout("$('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/wtrhwt.jpg')", 1000);
   setTimeout("$('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/t8yejty.jpg')", 1000);
   setTimeout("$('#person1').attr('src', 'lastwavewinnerimages/t2tgw8.jpg')", 1000);
   ..
   ..
   ..
   ..
   ..
   setTimeout("loopImages()",0);
}
```

onload = "loopImages()"

Comment: The last line will queue up loopImages to run again after zero milliseconds, and the list of setTimeouts are all scheduled to run at the same time. Instead they should be queued to run one after another. Also, it would be better to pass in a function reference instead of a string to setTimeout: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#evil

Comment: Also, please don't use the `onLoad` attribute. Attach an event listener.

Comment: the last line only will call the loopImages once. This should work fine. It is not a setInterval

Comment: @littlecegian once, but immediately, and, as you said, it's recursive.

Comment: recursive thing is probably bad. But i guess the code meets the intent, maybe not in the standards. Thanks for the comments

Comment: @littlecegian: calling loopImages will set up a timeout to call loopImages again, which will set up a timeout to call loopImages again, which will set up a timeout to call loopImages again, which will set up a timeout to call loopImages again...

Comment: Using `setInterval (loopImages,0)` would be even worse. Not only it would grind the browser to a halt, it would also explode the browser's memory (or run out of handles).

Comment: Not that it doesn't explode the browser's memory as it is now ;-)